# Where does Visual Studio / nuget download nuget packages by default on restore

Tags: .net, nuget

I wanted to explore what NuGet packages were actually downloaded on my computer and where, I searched through the web but somehow couldn't find a clear answer on the default location of nuget packages, when you change nothing. I was quite astonished not to find that informatoin, I must be missing something.

Comment: oh I see I'm downvoted without a comment ^^, maybe I should have posted this to another site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question : `C:\Users\<you>\.nuget\packages`. I found this by right-clicking one of my project's nuget dependencies and looking at the Properties pane, turns out it wasn't that hard after all.

It's all explained in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders), it's called the *global-packages* folder.

- on Windows it's `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`
- on Mac/Linux it's `~/.nuget/packages`